# docker swarm: How to inspect ingress-endpoint container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I inspect ingress I getting info about containers:

```
 $docker inspect ingress
"Containers": {
            "1234567890": {
                "Name": "gateway.1.qwertyuiop",
                "EndpointID": "12345678990",
                "MacAddress": "00:11:22:33:44:55",
                "IPv4Address": "10.255.0.11/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ingress-sbox": {
                "Name": "ingress-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "1234567890",
                "MacAddress": "00:11:22:33:44:55",
                "IPv4Address": "10.255.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

Then I can inspect first container but inspecting `ingress-endpoint` returns nothing

```
$ docker inspect ingress-endpoint
[]
```

What I'm trying to find is the local ip for ingress-endpoint in the swarm node.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need that, but if you are looking for where incoming packets are being routed to, you may look at iptables.

```
iptables -n -t nat -L DOCKER-INGRESS
```

On my setup (where one of the services publishes the port 80) I get following output:

```
Chain DOCKER-INGRESS (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:172.18.0.2:80
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

So `172.18.0.2` is the IP address of the ingress container

Notice that this `ingress-sbox` container is part of both networks that Swarm mode creates for you:

- ingress
- docker_gwbridge

This is all part of Linux network namespaces, as explained in this very good post: https://neuvector.com/network-security/docker-swarm-container-networking/ which I recommend reading.

```
# cd /var/run/
# ln -s docker/netns .
# ip netns exec ingress_sbox ip addr
```

This gives (on my system):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: eth0@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0a:ff:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.255.0.2/16 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.255.0.4/32 brd 10.255.0.4 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: eth1@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet 172.18.0.2/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

You can also run iptables commands from within those network namespaces to try and follow how packets get *magically* routed...

Answer (score 0):

As running `docker inspect ingress-endpoint` giving output of `[]`, it very possibly means such endpoint is a stale container, which still hooks `ingress` network. You might want to disconnect the network, remove such container then re- join Swarm cluster, by doing

`docker network disconnect ingress --force ingress-endpoint`

`docker network rm ingess`